# Windows 7 - Task Manager not showing processes

Tags: windows-7, windows

**Hi all, I have a problem where the task manager on Windows 7 isn't showing any of the processes.**

Not showing processes

[image: Not showing processes]

**I can still close programs using arrow keys. Can anyone help me?**

Closing processes

[image: Closing processes]

Comment: What happens if you maximize the window so it is full-screen? It almost looks like it has a huge column width. Also, try rightclicking the column header and see if you can add columns.

Comment: I don't have a Windows 7 to hand but is there a preferences value under:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TaskManager.  If so, if you close Task Manager, Rename that value and restart Task Manager does it help?

Comment: Restore/replace `Taskmgr.exe.mui` file in "C:\Windows\System32\en-US\"

Comment: @LPChip good idea pointing bad column sizes, I was writing a comment noting that it couldn't be a huge column because there is no horizontal scrollbar when the (possible) real problem struck me (I always have the horizontal bar visible because I have a very, very large column for Command line).

Answer (score 2):

*(Kudos to @LPChip who gave me the idea of bad column sizes)*

It seems that you have a problem with column widths, it's like all columns get a zero width, I was able to reproduce your problem dragging all the columns to the left.

To fix it put the cursor in the left border of the column title bar, the cursor shape will change to a resize double arrow like in the screenshot below. Then click and drag to the right and the last column will appear, repeat it with the rest of columns until the cursor changes again to the standard arrow (in that moment there are no more columns hidden).

[image]

Comment: Good call. I already thought it was a width issue, but I forgot that a size of 0 is also possible.